# Running numbers with an iterator (homework)

Tags: java, iterator

i have this assignment that i cannot solve.
This question has probably been asked multiple times but i failed to find it so forgive me if i am indeed repeating a simple question.

---

This is the assignment:

> Create a class named Benchmark.
>   Write a method that counts from 1 to 8.000.000 by 1s. Every time the count reaches a multiple of 1.000.000 print that number on the screen. Use your watch to time how long the loop takes.
>   Alternatively, you can use the system clock to time the duration of your program.  You can do this by using the static method currentTimeMillis in the class System.  See the documentation of the JDK for a detailed explanation on using this method.
>   The program should produce an output like this:
>
> 0
>   1000000
>   2000000
>   3000000
>   4000000
>   5000000
>   6000000
>   7000000
>   8000000

---

I found out that i need to use an iterator in order to get this done.
But my teacher is not available right now and i can't seem to find out how to use this.

Again: sorry for the newbie question, if someone could help me out with this.. I'd be forever gratefull ;)

Thanks for reading and thanks in advance for any help given!

Comment: Please do not use the homework tag on new questions. (and please *do* tag with the language you're using)

Comment: Isn't the homework tag fitable for any homework related question?
Added the language.

Comment: No, the homework tag is obsolete; there's a very slow ongoing process of removing it from existing questions.

Comment: @Tristen so your question is how to use a Java iterator?

Comment: @ wooble I see, i will bear that in mind

@ andy, yes i think so. im really new to this and the teacher isn't around to give the basics so im forced to turn to the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8000000; i++) {
    if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

If you also want to measure the time:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end;
for (int i = 1; i <= 8000000; i++) {
    if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println((end-start));
        start = end;
    }
}
```

Comment: might want to change i to 1 and i <=8000000 or else it'll never hit 8,000,000

Comment: @JeffHawthorne oops, changed it :-)